# set variables from the window frame is now visible, WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, window, parent, mahapps.metro

I'm making an application where I open several windows at different times, and each window has a frame that incorporates according to click several pages.

What I need is for me to take the variable of MainWindow from within the page, built by frame.

doing so:

```
 public partial class SearchPage : Page
    {
        public SearchPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        }
    }
```

However, it takes the first Window open, and not the current ones, but the one that always keeps me open to the launch of the program. No way to get the parent window of the time that is visible? I to close the septum to `Visibility.Hidden();` and to reopen `Visibility.Visible();`

I'm using mahapps metroWindow

Comment: Please post more code, and it is still a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. `Application.Current.MainWindow` will allways give you the first window, you can access other windows collection with `App.Current.Windows`.

Comment: i'm try get page after InitializeComponent, i have added code from codebehind the SearchPage

Comment: So do you need MainWindow or the parent window of a SearchPage? And what do you want to do with the window? Can you also add some code where you displaying your page?

Comment: i have the MainWindow.xaml with inside a frame that load SearchPage.xaml, i wish get variabiles of textbox from MainWindow.xaml

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you need, I need more code, sorry. Here I tried to to the same (as I think) that you're doing. Please correct me if I misunderstood.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Main Window" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="textbox" Text="test" TextChanged="textbox_TextChanged"></TextBox>
    <Frame x:Name="fr">            
    </Frame>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication2
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            fr.Navigate(new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }

        private void textbox_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fr != null) fr.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApplication2.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
Title="Page1">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>MY PAGE</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>The text in window is: </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock x:Name="tb"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainWindow w = (MainWindow) App.Current.MainWindow;
            tb.Text = w.textbox.Text;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can walk up the visual tree to find the corresponsing `MetroWindow` instance:

```cs
var window = this.TryFindParent<MetroWindow>();
```

`TryFindParent` is an extension method defined in `MahApps.Metro.Controls.TreeHelper`, so you must add `using MahApps.Metro.Controls;`